# apt-get output all in Chinese

Tags: debian, locale

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install task-chinese-s-desktop
```

to get a Mandarin Chinese desktop environment (I'm learning the language). But I found it so irritating that I did

```
sudo apt-get remove task-chinese-s-desktop
```

again. I found that even after removing this, its output is in Chinese still:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树       
正在读取状态信息... 完成       
升级了 0 个软件包，新安装了 0 个软件包，要卸载 0 个软件包，有 8 个软件包未被升级。
```

Why is this happening? What determines what language this program is in? If it matters, I'm on Linux Mint.

In case this provides anyone with a clue: I upgraded the initramfs (unrelated to this issue, I just have a habit of making sure my packages are up-to-date). I got this warning:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
Warning: No support for locale: zh_CN.utf8
```

It's not `$LANG`:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: Look in /etc/default/locale to see if it has changed your locale.

Comment: @arochester That did the trick. It had zh_CN all over which I changed to en_GB. Question is then, why did I spot that when I did `echo $LANG`? Anyway, if you post that as an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From the terminal run:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

then :

```
locale-gen "en_GB.UTF-8"
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```